# Rollback transaction from trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In MS SQL Server 2008 R2, we want a pre-insert and pre-update trigger which checks something and allows or rollbacks (via `raiserror`) the running insert/update.

**Question**: In `INSTEAD OF` trigger. Does one really has to explicitly write the insert or update? Because we want the default insert or update to be done and only do the "precheck".

Comment: What is the nature of the "precheck"? Triggers do have an overhead managing the `inserted`/`deleted` tables. Is it something that can be enforced another way?

Comment: All we need is a unique constraint on triples (3 columns) ignoring empty strings in one column.

Comment: So for tuple `(a,b,c)` if `c` has a value of empty string you want to completely ignore that tuple for purposes of the unique constraint?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes! That's it. We want the tripple `(a,b,c)` to be unique iff `c` is nonempty.

Comment: In that case you can use a unique filtered index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix ON T(a,b,c) WHERE c <> ''
`

Comment: What Martin Smith said, but even if that weren't an option, an after insert/update trigger that rolls back the transaction would also roll back the insert/update, even if there's no explicit transaction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

You do need to write the explicit `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

The trigger runs `INSTEAD OF` the DML operation. If you leave the trigger blank then no action will happen other than the `INSERTED` / `DELETED` tables being created and populated in `tempdb`.

Although from discussion in the comments I would not use a trigger for this at all but use a unique filtered index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix ON T(a,b,c) WHERE c <> ''`. This is likely to be more performant and avoid potential logic issues when dealing with concurrency.

Comment: Thank you. And what are the aliases for inserted and updated rows in those DML operations?

Comment: @James - `INSERTED` and `DELETED` but these are tables not rows. The trigger fires once per statement. So `INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT * FROM INSERTED` would be a typical `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

Comment: And what if the `YourTable` contains identity column and many many other columns. `SELECT *` is a problem then, isn't it?

Comment: @James - Yes. `IDENTITY` columns and other types of computed columns would need to be excluded from the `SELECT` and `INSERT` lists.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support partial/filtered unique indexes :(

Answer (score 4):

You probably do not want an `INSTEAD OF` trigger unless you want to replace the actual insert or update.  In your case, you want a `FOR INSERT, UPDATE` trigger instead.

This example trigger prints a message to the client when anyone tries to add or change data in the titles table.

```
USE pubs
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'reminder' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER reminder
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder
ON titles
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS RAISERROR ('inserts and updates to the titles table is not allowed', 16, 1)
GO
```

You could also use things like `IF EXISTS` or `COLUMNS_UPDATED` as well.

Here another example that uses rollback.

```
USE pubs
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'employee_insupd' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER employee_insupd
GO
CREATE TRIGGER employee_insupd
ON employee
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
/* Get the range of level for this job type from the jobs table. */
DECLARE @min_lvl tinyint,
   @max_lvl tinyint,
   @emp_lvl tinyint,
   @job_id smallint
SELECT @min_lvl = min_lvl, 
   @max_lvl = max_lvl, 
   @emp_lvl = i.job_lvl,
   @job_id = i.job_id
FROM employee e INNER JOIN inserted i ON e.emp_id = i.emp_id 
   JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = i.job_id
IF (@job_id = 1) and (@emp_lvl <> 10) 
BEGIN
   RAISERROR ('Job id 1 expects the default level of 10.', 16, 1)
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
ELSE
IF NOT (@emp_lvl BETWEEN @min_lvl AND @max_lvl)
BEGIN
   RAISERROR ('The level for job_id:%d should be between %d and %d.',
      16, 1, @job_id, @min_lvl, @max_lvl)
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

I'm not sure if you have a transaction or not, but in your case you would want something like the following:

```
USE myDatabase

    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
          WHERE name = 'myTable' AND type = 'TR')
       DROP TRIGGER tr_myTrigger
    GO
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_myTrigger
    ON myTable
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
    AS

if(exists(select * from inserted where rtrim(c) <> ''))
begin
  -- check to make sure the insert(s) are unique

    if(exists(
      select * from inserted i
      join dbo.myTable t on i.a = t.a and i.b = t.b and i.c = t.c)

    begin
      raiserror('Duplicate(s) found', 16, 1)
      rollback transaction
    end
end
```