# sql DELETE trigger won't rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, rollback

The trigger is supposed to rollback if the statement in the SELECT exists. The thing is, it doesn't. When I only run the SELECT from the trigger, it shows that a row exists. But when I try DELETE with the same values as I have hard coded in the trigger, the trigger fires but it does not do a rollback. Anyone got any ideas what might be wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_del ON Projektbefattningar

FOR DELETE
AS

  SELECT @befNr = Befattningsnr, @pNr = pNr, @EtappNr = Etappnr FROM deleted
-- Not currently using these. Using hard coded values to illustrate my problem

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM projektbefattningar
        WHERE Befattningsnr = 2 AND pNr = 1 and Etappnr = 1 AND Anställningsnr is not null
        )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null', 16, 1)
        --THROW 50001, 'Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null', 1;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END

GO
```

Comment: Why don't you use an instead of trigger?

Comment: Why are throwing exception before rollback? Try first to rollback.

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072627/rollback-transaction-from-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_del ON Projektbefattningar
FOR DELETE
AS
SELECT @befNr = Befattningsnr
    ,@pNr = pNr
    ,@EtappNr = Etappnr
FROM deleted

-- Not currently using these. Using hard coded values to illustrate my problem
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM deleted
        WHERE Befattningsnr = 2
            AND pNr = 1
            AND Etappnr = 1
            AND Anställningsnr IS NOT NULL
        )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (
            'Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null'
            ,16
            ,1
            )

    --THROW 50001, 'Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null', 1;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use FOR DELETE you consider that this TRIGGER will fired after the delete statement is complete. To Verify a condition before DELETE you need to use INSTEAD OF DELETE. Your Trigger declaration will be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_del ON Projektbefattningar
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
```

Now To Confirm your delete statement you need to include the delete alghouth it will not be deleted. 
The final procedure will be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_del ON Projektbefattningar

INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

  SELECT @befNr = Befattningsnr, @pNr = pNr, @EtappNr = Etappnr FROM deleted
-- Not currently using these. Using hard coded values to illustrate my problem

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM projektbefattningar
        WHERE Befattningsnr = 2 AND pNr = 1 and Etappnr = 1 AND Anställningsnr is not null
        )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null', 16, 1)
        --THROW 50001, 'Could not delete, Anställningsnr is not null', 1;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

       DELETE FROM YourTableToDelete Where idOfYourTable in ( Select idOfYourTable from Deleted )
    END

GO
```

Comment: Also good solution to the problem that i had with the triggers before when i asked the question, nice! Thanks. Also INSTEAD OF DELETE doesn't work with foreign keys so that's not so good.